# Alamofire does not set `If-None-Match` header automatically

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have an iOS app that making API calls to 2 different servers (`server A` and `server B`) using Alamofire 5.2.2. Based on my understanding and what I read on StackOverflow, Alamofire should automatically set the `If-None-Match` request header as long as the cache policy is set to `.useProtocolCachePolicy`, and return status code `200` to the app if the server responded with status code `304`.

I am able to make an API call to `server A` and Alamofire is setting the `If-None-Match` header as expected. However, by using the same set of code, Alamofire is not setting the `If-None-Match` header when I make API call to `server B`.

One thing I notice is that `server A` is using a strong validation:

```
Etag: "7266bc2f1b245365bb1a74da5185bca6"
```

Whereas, `server B` is using a weak validation:

```
ETag: W/"6672-pKPf8kg1eUMH8msoW0et1yskcQQ"
```

I also tried to manually set the `If-None-Match` header when calling `server B` and the server responded with status code `304`. I was expecting Alamofire to return status code `200` to my app, instead, it returns status code `304`.

Any idea why Alamofire does not automatically set the `If-None-Match` when making API call to `server B`? Is that an Alamofire bug or just a server config issue? Anything I can do to get the same behavior as making API call to `server A`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the reason for my problem is because `server B` has the response header `Cache-Control = no-store` and Alamofire is respecting this header and ignore the given Etag.

Answer (score 0):

A 304 response seems expected, as most servers use that to indicate the cached data is still good. From [Microsoft's MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/ETag#caching_of_unchanged_resources):

> The server compares the client's ETag (sent with If-None-Match) with the ETag for its current version of the resource, and if both values match (that is, the resource has not changed), the server sends back a 304 Not Modified status, without a body, which tells the client that the cached version of the response is still good to use (fresh).

Alamofire doesn't do anything here, it's all handled by `URLSession` under the hood.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that still doesn't explain why server A and server B give a different result. Do you think that has something to do with the server-side configuration?

Comment: Probably. If it's returning different tags it's probably different in other ways too.